# Does the phrase "legend has it" mean a legend is factually accurate?

Tags: phrases

What does the term "legend has it" specifically mean? Does it just mean "There is a legend which says...", or does it mean "There is a legend which is actually accurate in saying..."?

My understanding is that a legend "has it" when it's factually accurate. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"[Legend] has it"* in this usage simply means *says* or *states*.

It could be expanded to *"has it down as"*, or is probably best rephrased as has already been stated as *"according to [legend]"*.

Answer (score 14):

It means "according to legend" and has no bearing on accuracy. It's similar to saying "rumor has it."

Comment: +1:  Although, as some of the other answerers mentioned, the fact that you're calling it a "legend" does mean that you have your doubts about its accuracy.  (otherwise you wouldn't be classifying it as "legend")

Answer (score 1):

My understanding, from most of the usage I have seen, is that it means the former. As in, "...a legend which says...". However, I think the phrase is most often used for *popular* legends.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of truthfulness, it only implies that other people would corroborate the story. In other words, you say it in place of the more desperate, "I am not making this up!". It does not imply factuality.

Answer (score 1):

"Legend has it" means there is a popular belief people hold and not necessarily true. Don't attach words like *factually* or *accurately* to the meaning because the idea might not be true to all and can't be proved, it is like a myth or belief, a little more than rumor because it is held from ages ago.